# CXF-CodeGen-Plugin - Disable documentation generation

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, javadoc, cxf-codegen-plugin

I currently am `cxf-codegen-plugin` to convert a WSDL to Java code (`wdsl2java`).

I cannot change the WSDL definition, since it is provided by an external source, but this file contains documentation that causes the Javadoc generation to fail with the following error:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] * Group of elements containing the details of a customer?s credit card
information, needed to establish pre-authorized payments, to charge a credit
card, to provide a guarantee for hardware, or to hold funds.
[INFO] [ERROR] ^
[INFO] [ERROR]
[INFO] [ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe"
```

How can I disable documentation generation in CXF Codegen? I can't seem to find an answer in any online documentation, including on Maven Central Repository. Is it possible at all?